# Question about a song I’m trying to learn how to play

Tags: piano

I’m a beginner in learning how to play piano to write music. The song I’m trying to learn how to play is by Christina Aguilera. The song is called "I Will Be." So, for instance it says play RH c# but going according to my piano chart there’s more than one c# so which one do I play and the same question for all the notes to play. Here is a link to the song so maybe someone can help me out http://aishiras_tradingpost.tripod.com/music/i_will_be.txt and here is a different link with sheet music

Answer (score 3):

Kaylee, when you say...

> according to my piano chart there's more than one c#

...you probably mean that c# can be played in several octaves. So on a full 88 key piano there are 7 c#'s, but the Tripod page doesn't tell you which octave, or range, to use.

A very simple way to decide in which octave to play is to **use middle C as a reference point**. [Middle C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(musical_note)#Middle_C) is the C near the middle of the keyboard.

Try playing the **right hand above** middle C and the **left hand below** middle C. Also, you may want to place the hands into different octaves to **avoid collisions** of the hands. Notice in the first measure there is an "A" in the right hand and "(A)" in the left hand. If those two A's are in the same octave, your hands will collide. That can be hard to play and also can create a kind of repeated note effect that may not sound right. You could drop the left hand by an octave to avoid such collisions.

This will put most of the notes in a good range where the harmony will sound clear. If you play too low the chords can get "muddy" and harmony can become unclear. If you play too high it may sound too light or thin. There are times when playing in a very low or high range are appropriate, but staying around middle C is usually a safe bet if you are unsure what range to use.